# .htaccess - How to make an exception without redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So, I've a big problem with .htaccess. All addresses are redirected to app/webroot. I'd like to make an exception without redirection for my file: cron-5min.php.

My part .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule    ^cron-5min.php$ cron-5min.php
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

Unfortunately, when I type **address.com/cron-5min.php** it redirects me to file for path /app/webroot/cron-5min.php

I tried to add instruction **RewriteRule ^cron-5min.php$ cron-5min.php** in a variety of places in .htaccess, but nothing helped.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That looks suspiciously like CakePHP, with a development install (apache doc root should point to the webroot folder); why don't you simply move the file _into_ the webroot then there's no rewrite complexity. Incidentally - cron jobs are not normally web accessible - they are [console commands](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rewrite rule does not terminate the chain. Note your other two rewrite rules are appended with [L] (Last). This indicates that no more rules should be processed when it matches.

You can also use the [END] flag, which is the same as [L], but no more rules will be processed from subsequent .htaccess files in this requrest.

More info on both these flags and using flags are in the documentation:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html